# The page isn't working. url.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

My Laravel website is successfully running. But from yesterday I got an error while browsing the site.

**Error is**

> The page isn't working. url.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

As I remembered I have only changed one of my view page , nothing else.

I have already googling for the solution but not solved yet.

Anybody help please ? If any query please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved !! It's just a PHP version related problem. I have just changed the PHP version from 5.6 to 7.0 in PHP configuration of my cPanel.